# I need to insert data from a column from another table with different data type and the value is based on a lookup table

Tags: sql-server

I need to import data taken from table_1.column_1 (BOND.MOODYS_RATING) to table_2.column_2 (LCDOffering.KeyValidCreditRatingsMoody)

WHERE:

1. MOODYS_RATING data type is nvarchar(10) and KeyValidCreditRatingsMoody data type is int(4)
2. Each value in the column MOODYS_RATING represent a lookup value, being KeyValidCreditRatingsMoody the key for that lookup value
3. KeyValidCreditRatingsMoody values are equal to KeyValidCreditRatings, taken from  the table ValidCreditRatings, while MOODYS_RATING values are equal to the field CreditRating, also from the table ValidCreditRatings, subject to certain restrictions, which can be summarized in this query:

   ```
   select * from Lookup..ValidCreditRatings
   where KeyInstnRatingAgency = 108462 
   and KeyValidCreditRatings <=21 order by keyvalidcreditratings
   ```

Can you please help me build an insert statement that can fulfill all of these requirements?

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

You are not explaining very well what you mean by import (whether it is an insert or an update or a little bit of both), so it is hard to suggest a close enough prototype query for you to use directly or with minimal tweaking. However, the key issue, as I understand it, is to convert each `nvarchar(10)` value of `BOND.MOODYS_RATING` to a corresponding `int` key, looking up each string in `ValidCreditRatings.CreditRating` and taking the key from `ValidCreditRatings.KeyValidCreditRatings`.

That operation takes a simple inner join:

```
SELECT
  b.*,
  vcr.KeyValidCreditRatings
FROM
  BOND AS b
  INNER JOIN Lookup..ValidCreditRatings AS vcr
    ON b.MOODYS_RATING = vcr.CreditRating
WHERE
  vcr.KeyInstnRatingAgency = 108462 
  AND vcr.KeyValidCreditRatings <= 21
;
```

The `KeyValidCreditRatings` column in the output of this query will contain the values that you can write to `LCDOffering.KeyValidCreditRatingsMoody`.

A join can be used both in an `UPDATE` statement and in an `INSERT` statement (the `INSERT ... SELECT` variation). Use the join in the above example query as a basis for the actual query that will be importing data, adding other filters and/or joins as necessary and putting the `vcr.KeyValidCreditRatings` reference where the source for `LCDOffering.KeyValidCreditRatingsMoody` should go. By the latter I mean, if for instance, yours is an `UPDATE` statement, then you will probably have in the `SET` clause an assignment like this:

```
UPDATE
  LCDOffering
SET
  ...
  KeyValidCreditRatingsMoody = vcr.KeyValidCreditRatings,
  ...
FROM
  ...
```

And if it is an `INSERT ... SELECT` statement, then you will have `vcr.KeyValidCreditRatings` in the select list at the position corresponding to the `KeyValidCreditRatingsMoody` column's position in the target column list:

```
INSERT INTO
  LCDOffering (..., KeyValidCreditRatingsMoody, ...)
SELECT
  ..., vcr.KeyValidCreditRatings, ...
FROM
  ...
```